# javascript regexp for validating youtube embed url

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, youtube

how to write a regular expression in javascript for validating youtube embed link?
like i want to allow users to only type youtube embed url. and can i have the regexp variable independent? i mean the url has some features like controls, show info etc..

like the following url are valid

- `www.youtube.com/embed/tqJDf7IB4HI`
- `www.youtube.com/embed/tqJDf7IB4HI?rel=0&controls=0`

both are valid

but it is invalid if the url has different domain or any other embed url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validation purposes, i suggest you to use anchors. `\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters.

```
^www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/\S*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yY3cC8/1)

```
> /^www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/\S*$/.test('www.youtube.com/embed/tqJDf7IB4HI?rel=0&controls=0')
true
> /^www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/\S*$/.test('www.youtube.com/embed/tqJDf7IB4HI')
true
```

Comment: add `http://` at the start , like `^http:\/\/www\.`,  or `^http:\/\/youtube` or `^(http:\/\/)?www\.` choose the one which satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
function testURL(url) {
 return /www.youtube.com\/embed\/[A-z0-9]+/.test(url);
}

alert(testURL("www.youtube.com/embed/tqJDf7IB4HI?rel=0&controls=0"));
```